# how do you make an object callable and attach functions to it at the same time

Tags: javascript

I'm using winston as a logger and in it you have a `format` namespace and function at the same time, so i can both call `format()` and access other functions via the namespace `format.someFunction()` as illustrated in the code below. Now i'm wondering how i can create an object like this myself?

```js
const isRequest = format((info, _opts) => {
    if (info.isRequest) {
        return info
    }
    return false
})

export const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        }),
        format.printf((info) => {
            return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
        })
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            filename: errorLog,
            level: 'error'
        }),
        new transports.File({
            filename: requestLog,
            format: format.combine(isRequest())
        }),
        new transports.File({
            filename: combinedLog
        })
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new transports.File({
            filename: exceptionsLog
        })
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's JavaScript function expression. If you export it, it works pretty much the same. Hope this is what you mean.

[More about function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

```js
let sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello")
}
sayHello.sayWorld = function() {
  console.log("World")
}

sayHello();
sayHello.sayWorld();
```

Comment: ok that clears up that part thanks! now i would need to mock this in jest too, any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: @HenriDeBel Sadly I'm not familiar or ever worked with jest. You could make a total different question for that.

Comment: yeah i figured i would know how to mock it with the answer to my first question thanks anyway :)